# INSERT data FROM sql query with one constant value in MS Access with SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I am trying to create a form for MS Access where you at first search for companies in a table based on criteria. The returned data is simply the names of the matching companies. I then want to take these names and add them to a different table.

So far there are 3 tables: one stores the User Names (tblStartup), one Stores the Company Names (tblVC) and one shall be used to save the matches (tblContact).

The problem I have is that I want to add a constant user name alongside the data from the query.

So e.g. "MAX" searches for companies that are from Automotive. He  gets a list of matching companies e.g BMW, DAIMLER and AUDI.
So the data which should be added to the table tblContact would be:

```
MAX           BMW
MAX           DAIMLER
MAX           AUDI
```

INSERT INTO...SELECT... doesn´t work because I not only need to add the Info from the query but also a constant which the User selects from a Combobox(e.g. the user selects "MAX" and then uses the button "query" to find matching companies for MAX, then the button "add to Contacts".

This is the code I have so far:

```
Dim sql As String
sql = "INSERT INTO tblContact(txtNameStart, txtNameVC) " & _
      "SELECT txtName FROM tblVC WHERE Branche ='" & Me.cboBranchen & "';"
```

So how do I put my constant User Name inside the query). Would it be something like SELECT... AND VALUES...?

Regards
Max

Comment: Save it, and use it in the insert query.

Comment: What code have you already tried, and what was the issue with it?

Comment: An `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...` is fine for constant values, you can use `INSERT INTO .... SELECT "MyConstant", Column1 FROM MyTable`

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth This is what I was looking for. Thank you very much!

Comment: Reposting as an answer to show this question has been answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use an `INSERT INTO .... SELECT ....` statement, with one column and one constant value.

Example:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO tblContact(txtNameStart, txtNameVC) " & _
      "SELECT """ & Me.cboName & """, txtName FROM tblVC WHERE Branche ='" & Me.cboBranchen & "';"
```

Comment: `"INSERT INTO tblContact(Investitionsvolumen, StartUp, VC) SELECT '" & Me.txtKapital & "', IdStartUp FROM tblStartup WHERE txtName ='" & Me.txtNameStartUp & "', IdVC FROM tblVC " WHERE Branche=" & Me.cboBranchen AND InvestStart <= " & Me.txtKapital AND InvestEnde >=" & Me.txtKapital & _
          " AND Unternehmensphase =" & Me.cboPhase & ";"` How do I Need to Change it, when there is another SELECT from a different table?

Comment: That's a different question, and one I'd be happy to answer if you'd ask it as a question, not as a comment.